# Comparing types in C++

Tags: c++, architecture, component-based

I'm working on a custom engine where I have 2 different transform classes, one for 2D and one for 3D. I'm using a #define to choose which transform class to use and using that definition instead of the classname in places where the logic should be the same. I am at a part now where I want them to have different logic and wanted to do a comparison to branch off for that.
What do I need to do to get this to work?

```
class Transform2D;
class Transform3D;

#define TransformClass Transform2D

if(TransformClass == Transform2D)
{
  //like this
}
else    
{
  //like that
}
```

Type id worked for that. How do you handle?

```
if ( typeid(TransformClass) == typeid(Transform2D) )
{
    ittransform->SetRotation(0);
    ittransform->SetScale(Vector2D(defaultScale, defaultScale));
}
else
{
    ittransform->SetRotation(Vector3f());
    ittransform->SetScale(Vector3f(defaultScale, defaultScale, defaultScale));
}
```

Comment: This kind of type checking is usually the indication of a poor architecture/class design. Either use overloaded functions, like Sean suggested, or, define a top level interface class that is implemented by either a transform2D or transform3D

Comment: Instead of #define just make your function a template that operates on both Transform2D/3D classes using common interface like Sean suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Use function decomposition (break your logic into sub-functions) and then make use of overloading.

```
void do_something(Transform2D const& t) {
  ...
}

void do_something(Transform3D const& t) {
  ...
}

void test() {
  TransformClass tc = ...
  do_something(tc); // invokes the desired overload
}
```

Also, use a typedef or type alias instead of a define, e.g.

```
#if defined(USE_3D)
using TransformClass = Transform3D;
#else
using TransformClass = Transform2D;
#endif
```

You can also define the alias via std::conditional and be even more functional-y and C++-y.

Comment: Does `using TransformClass = Transform2D;` do the same thing as the #define or does it have more/different behaviour.`

Comment: @ColinAvrech: It has _slightly_ different behavior.  Namely, if you name a variable `TransformClass`, it's actually called `TransformClass` and not `Transform3D`.  A few other differences.

Comment: What is the jargon/term for that use?

Comment: It's a "type alias" and is similar to a typedef, but the using syntax is easier to read and a bit more powerful (it allows the use of parametrized aliases, aka alias templates). Basically, just use it where you have used a typedef before (I think it's a complete replacement, but maybe there's a corner case I'm unaware of).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use if() in this situation.

Since you're coding with the pre-processor, stick with it:

```
# if USING_3D
    3d code
# else
    2d code
# endif
```

and if you strive to keep most of the methods and ancilliary classes looking broadly the same, you'll probably manage to avoid too much use of #if

Old C code was littered with this stuff, and it was considered good. However nowadays, it's very old fashioned. Think thrice before you continue down this path.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest option is to create an extra define, something like this:

```
#define USING_CLASS_2D 1

#if USING_CLASS_2D
#define TransformClass Transform2D
#else
#define TransformClass Transform3D
#endif

if (USING_CLASS_2D)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: If adopting this approach, then why even use `if()` logic? In this case, the correct would be a preprocessor `#if` or `#ifdef`.

Comment: Why do this over `typedef`?

Comment: I used `#define` and `if`, as that's what was used in the question. You could use a typedef instead.